# For which values of n is $f'$ (a) continous at $0$ (b) differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined $f(x)= x^n
>  \; \forall x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=0 \; \forall x < 0$.
>
> For which values
>    of $n$ is $f'$ (a) continous at $0$, and (b) differentiable at $0$?

To study the derivative function, I would need the derivative function first

For $x>0$ $f(x)=x^n \Rightarrow f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$

for $x < 0$ $f(x)= 0 \Rightarrow f'(x)=0 $

for $x=0$ I need to find $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} x^{n-1} = 0 $ if $n \geq 2$ or $1$ if $n=1$

Now these cases depend on $x$ aswell as $n$. So how am I supposed to proceed this way to get final answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are correct and they show that $\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=0$. They also show that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0$, unless $n=1$. Therefore, unless $n=1$, $f'$ is continuous at $0$. By a similar argument, $f'$ is differentiable at $0$ unless $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: why for n=2 shouldn’t be differentiable?

Comment: @gimusi No. In that case, $f'(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f'(x)=2x$ otherwise. So, $f'$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: ah ok I was answering for f(x)...sorry!